# How to redeploy artifact with liberty-maven-plugin?

Tags: deployment, maven-plugin, websphere-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I have IBM Liberty server running on my machine and want to redeploy my WAR using corresponding maven plugin.

The documentation says that there are goals like `deploy` , `undeploy` , `install-apps` . Currently I am using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-apps</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-apps</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <serverHome>c:/my-liberty-instance</serverHome>
        <serverName>myServerName</serverName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it's not good for me because it requires *the server instance to be stopped before*. If it's running - a new WAR is deployed (it replaces the old one) but no new changes are caught up.

I've tried to use `deploy` goal but once it copies WAR to the `dropins` directory - it starts searching some console.log file for some line that should indicate if app is started and FAILS.

Example for `undeploy` goal : `CWWKM2022E: Failed to undeploy application app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war. The Stop application message cannot be found in console.log.`
But the same message appears for `deploy` , `stop-server` .

**Is there a convenient way to redeploy WAR using liberty-maven-plugin where I don't need to restart the server ?**
I just want to build a new WAR - deploy it; want the server to catch up the changes and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the install-apps goal to install the project war file without your liberty server instance stopped.  But you need to use liberty-maven-plugin version `1.3 or above`, and also include `<installAppPackages>project</installAppPackages>` to the plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-apps</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-apps</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <installDirectory>c:/my-liberty-instance</installDirectory>
        <serverName>myServerName</serverName>
        <installAppPackages>project</installAppPackages>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It works but the server does not catch up a new changes. What I mean is I change the code, build a new WAR, deploy (I can see updated WAR in dropins) but Liberty does not redeploy it actually. I need to restart the server to get my changes deployed. If I remove an old WAR first, paste a new one manually - everything works, but the plugin just replaces  WAR file and Liberty does not redeploy in that case.

Comment: Did you configure applicationMonitor in your server.xml?  if you do, you need to set the updateTrigger to its default value. `<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="polled"/>`

Comment: It really helped. Thanks !