# How to find a detailed document about what is Liberty Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, websphere-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

Maybe it is a dumb quesion but I really cannot find a good document about what is Liberty Maven Plugin and what it is used for ?

I have checked some posts like [How to redeploy artifact with liberty-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267433/how-to-redeploy-artifact-with-liberty-maven-plugin) but it is not about the basic things. I need a good basic document,

1. what is it?
2. why should we use it?
3. why should not we use it?
4. what are the advantages ?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Liberty Maven Plugin provides a number of goals for managing a Liberty runtime, including downloading and installing the runtime, starting/stopping a server, installing features, and deploying applications. The plugin is open source and the code and documentation is available on Github here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven

There is a guide and sample project on building and testing a simple web application using the Liberty Maven Plugin and Open Liberty here: https://openliberty.io/guides/maven-intro.html